# Does rules_js support yarn?

Tags: typescript, bazel, bazel-rules-js

All examples in `rules_js` https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_js seems to be with pnpm. Can I use `rules_js` with `yarn` instead of `pnpm`?

Answer (score 0):

Found in their [docs](https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_js/tree/main/docs#fetch-third-party-packages-from-npm). TL;DR; No.

You can either

1. use pnpm to transfer the existing `yarn.lock` to `pnpm-lock.yaml` and check `pnpm-lock.yaml` in or
2. use `yarn_lock` in `npm_translate_lock` to transfer `yarn.lock` to `pnpm-lock.yaml` at run time, without checking `pnpm-lock.yaml` in.